# Unable read OCR PDF in Python

Tags: python, pdf, ocr, pythonmagick

I'm trying to read a .pdf file for the first time in python, This file has OCR in it.

```
from wand.image import Image
from PIL import Image as PI
#import pyocrfrom PythonMagick import Image
from PythonMagick import Image
import pyocr.builders
import io

im = Image()
im.read(r"D:/test.pdf")
```

I have downloaded PythonMagick file which has .whl extension,  as directed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984357/pythonmagick-cant-find-my-pdf-files)
But still I get error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PythonMagick'

How and what step should be followed so that I could be able to read the OCR PDF in python.
Any suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`.whl` is not the file you meant do download. Install `pip` tools and use `pip install PythonMagick` command. Installing pip is a little bit complicated if you are using Windows.

Comment: This gives error "C:\Users\Admin1>pip install PythonMagick
Collecting PythonMagick
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PythonMagick (from ver
sions: )
No matching distribution found for PythonMagick"

Comment: Make sure you are using python2 and it's pip. Not the python3 one.

Comment: I'm executing the command from command prompt "python -m pip install PythonMagick"... but still gives error  "  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PythonMagick (from ver
sions: )
No matching distribution found for PythonMagick"