# imagemagick won't recognize new path to Ghostscript

Tags: window, imagemagick, ghostscript

I'm trying to convert some PDFs to jpegs using imagemagick . I'm working on win 10, 64 with python 3.62 - 64 bit and wand 0.4.4. I've been able to get wand working with ImageMagick-6.9.9-Q16-HDRI. I have all this set up on a E USB flash drive. I've set both the Path and MAGICK_HOME env vars  to

```
E:\ImageMagick-6.9.9-Q16-HDR;E:\gs\bin
```

Originally I  installed ghostscript 9.22 - 64 at E:/gs9.22 , but the I read ( [PythonMagick can't find my pdf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984357/pythonmagick-cant-find-my-pdf-files/13986768#13986768)) that 64 bit may not work so I deleted that and got ghostscript 9.22 - 32 bit, which I installed as above.

I ran:

```
$ convert myfile.pdf test.jpg
convert.exe: FailedToExecuteCommand `"E:/gs9.22/bin/gswin64c.exe" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=png
alpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72"  "-sOutputFile=C:/Users/MYaCCount/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-9524p6yKrXNmpJc3%d" "-fC:/Users/MYaCCount/AppData/Local/Te
mp/magick-9524TRGHmKoW5SkX" "-fC:/Users/MYaCCount/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-9524pKGelk0Un3Bp"' (The system cannot find the file specified.
) @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/459.
convert.exe: PDFDelegateFailed `The system cannot find the file specified.
' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/809.
convert.exe: no images defined `test.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
```

Why is the system looking for the 64 bit ghostscript path (which I deleted) ? I have closed and reopened my editor and the environmental var editor.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the regedit utility to manually go through and remove all traces of 'ImageMagick'. The included uninstall utility in Imagemagick did not remove everything. After this I was able to install new versions.